# Can you upload a Excel file with macros to Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

So my question is if i can upload it to google spreadsheet. I Have macros in my Excel file and i would like to keep them. Is it possible? Will it be somewow converted? I have 3 macros in my Excel file

Comment: @pnuts no. Why? Will it do it by itself?

Comment: @pnuts I just tried and i don't see my macros

Comment: @pnuts Dahell? And how do i get my macros back ?

Comment: Google Sheets is NOT Excel! Excel Macros are VBA working with an application in windows while Sheets executes automation at a Google server (that's the reason you can't import files which Google can't reach like intranet, while there exist some workarounds)... Also the scipting language is different to start with. To make it short: Excel macros are normally lost after upload to Google cus they will be converted to sheets (but you can use Drive as webspace without any converting)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot automatically convert an Excel document to Google Sheets while retaining VBA macro functionality; you would need to manually convert your VBA code into Google Apps Script.

Comment: I should have written my comment as an answer :P